# How to write an SQL query going through foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I am struggling to do the following:

I have two tables:

Table Employee; columns Employee_ID and Employee_Name. Employee_ID is primary key

Table  Emp_Salary; columns Employee_Salary which is a foreign key linked to employee_ID.

I am looking to get the salary for an employee whose ID is 40

so for example

```
Select employee_salary from EMP_Salary where Employee_ID equals 40;
```

unfortunately this does not work; any reason why? with the foreign> primary key relation this should be fine?

Another query that I cant get to work is:

```
 Select employee_Salary from EMP_Salary where Employee_name equals "Dan"
```

Any insight appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to learn about [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)ing tables.

Comment: `"Dan"` references a column name not a string value. String constants have to be enclosed in single quotes according to the SQL standard. So it should be `'Dan'`.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is nothing called `equals`. You may try this:

```
Select employee_salary from EMP_Salary where Employee_ID =40;
```

Similarly you may try this:

```
Select employee_Salary from EMP_Salary where Employee_name ="Dan"
```

You may also consider to look for [JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in MYSQL if you want to combine the two queries and get the results.

Something like this:

```
select EMPLOYEE_SALARY 
from EMPLOYEE E1 inner join EMP_SALARY E2 on E2.EMPLOYEE_ID = E1.EMPLOYEE_ID
where E1.EMPLOYEE_ID = 40;
```

or

```
select EMPLOYEE_SALARY 
from EMPLOYEE E1 inner join EMP_SALARY E2 on E2.EMPLOYEE_ID= E1.EMPLOYEE_ID
where E1.Employee_Name= 'Dan';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use = instead of equals:

```
Select employee_salary from EMP_Salary where Employee_ID = 40;
```

To get the salary by name you would JOIN both tables on Employee_ID and then put the Employee_name in the WHERE clause:

```
Select e.employee_salary 
FROM EMP_Salary es 
INNER JOIN employee e ON e.Employee_ID = es.Employee_ID 
WHERE e.Employee_name = 'Dan';
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `INNER JOIN`?

For example:

`select EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_SALARY
from EMPLOYEE A
inner join EMP_SALARY B
on B.ID_EMPLOYEE = A.ID_EMPLOYEE
where ID_EMPLOYEE = --numberhere`